# Select column name that may or may not exist in table, and get null value rather than error

Tags: sql, vertica

In vertica, is there a way to select a column that may or may not exist in a table, and get null as the value if the column does not exist?

The use case is stacking data from many tables, and writing a script to do that.  Not all columns exist in all table, so I would like to write one script like so, and just get null values where a certain column doesn't exist in a particular table.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT field1, field2, ... field100 from table1 ) UNION ALL 
(SELECT field1, field2, ... field100 from table2 ) UNION ALL 
(SELECT field1, field2, ... field100 from table3 ) UNION ALL 
(SELECT field1, field2, ... field100 from table4 ) UNION ALL 
...
(SELECT field1, field2, ... field100 from tablen ) UNION ALL
```

In our application, it's hard to know in advance whether every table has every named column, and if not, which columns are missing from each table.

EDIT:  Reference to same prior question  [Select columnValue if the column exists otherwise null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952442/select-columnvalue-if-the-column-exists-otherwise-null)

Comment: It is entirely unclear what the SQL code has to do with the question.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You can write `null as fieldX`, if particular table doesn't have column fieldX; in `union` you may even skip column name - `... field1, null, field3 ...` (not for first query though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance does not matter, try Vertica Flex Tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS allcols;                            
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS allbut1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS allbut4;

CREATE FLEX TABLE allcols();
INSERT INTO allcols(col1,col2,col3,col4)
          SELECT  1,  2,  3,  4
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 12, 13, 14
;
      
CREATE FLEX TABLE allbut1();
INSERT INTO allbut1(col2,col3,col4)
          SELECT  22, 23, 24
UNION ALL SELECT  32, 33, 34
;
      
CREATE FLEX TABLE allbut4();
INSERT INTO allbut4(col1,col2,col3)
          SELECT  21, 22, 23
UNION ALL SELECT  31, 32, 33
;
COMMIT;
\pset null (null)
          SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM allcols
UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM allbut1
UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM allbut4
;
-- out   col1  | col2 | col3 |  col4  
-- out --------+------+------+--------
-- out  1      | 2    | 3    | 4
-- out  11     | 12   | 13   | 14
-- out  (null) | 22   | 23   | 24
-- out  (null) | 32   | 33   | 34
-- out  21     | 22   | 23   | (null)
-- out  31     | 32   | 33   | (null)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the table has a primary key, you can try:

```
select . . . ,
       (select colx   -- no table alias!
        from t t2
        where t2.primary_key = t.primary_key
       ) as colx
from t cross join
     (select null as colx) x;
```

The way that scoping rules work in SQL is that `colx` will be "satisfied" from the subquery -- if `t` has the column.  Otherwise, it will reach out to the outer query and choose the value in `x`, because the outer `t` won't have the column either.

Comment: This is really clever, getting SQL to select a column by name that might not exist.

Comment: @prototype . . . I'm surprised you didn't accept this as the answer.

Comment: - You're right, this is the hard part of StackOverflow where I have to pick one and have to pick just one. The approach you propose will work with not just Vertica but probably any SQL dialect, and also broadened my understanding of SQL and so arguably is the better answer.  But I'd have to do this for each of N columns where N could be 1000 or more, and thus harder to write.  Vertica flex tables handle missing columns as hoped, and since that's the way I actually went chose that as the answer.  I tried transferring rep like a bounty but that seems not allowed by SO.