# How to ignore the columns if it is not present in a dataframe using spark-SQL?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is the dataframe from which I need to derive the output.

```
|A|B|C|E|F|
+---------+
|1|2|3|5|6| 
+---------+

Dataset<Row> set = spark.sql("select A as one, B as two, C as three ,D as four, E as five, F as six from input");
```

I need to skip the column 'D' if it is not present and move on to the other column(i.e) E.

If any of the column is not present then should print null and move on to the other column assignment.

Comment: What output do you currently get? An error since you're selecting a column that doesn't exist?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes i'm getting an error.. cannot resolve column "D".

Comment: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952442/select-columnvalue-if-the-column-exists-otherwise-null) detail how to work around missing columns, both in Scala Spark code and Spark sql, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

you can try and check first which columns exist in the input, for example:

```
input = spark.read.parquet(...)
cols = input.columns // returns an Array[String]
```

and then format your query accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).